# Uniqueness in a list of lists with lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists and some of the lists have a list in it:

```
x = [[[1,2],3],[[3,4],5], [[1,2],3]]
```

I have tried getting uniqueness to obtain:

```
x = [[[1,2],3],[[3,4],5]]
```

But no luck - any ideas?

I have so far used:

```
unique_data = [list(el) for el in set(tuple(el) for el in x)]
```

on a list of lists which works, but when adding in an element of a list within the list it fails

Comment: Show us the code you tried. Maybe it contained a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x = [[[1,2],3],[[3,4],5], [[1,2],3]]
print [item for idx, item in enumerate(x) if x.index(item) == idx]
# [[[1, 2], 3], [[3, 4], 5]]
```

We can do this in O(N) like this

```
x = [[[1,2],3],[[3,4],5], [[1,2],3]]
x = tuple(tuple(tuple(j) if isinstance(j, list) else j for j in i) for i in x)
from collections import OrderedDict
print [[list(j) if isinstance(j, tuple) else j for j in i] for i in OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys()]
# [[[1, 2], 3], [[3, 4], 5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you want.

```
x = [[[1,2],3],[[3,4],5], [[1,2],3]]
p = {hash(str(item)): item for item in x}
uniques = [ val for val in p.values()]
```

Comment: It would be better like this `p = {str(item): item for item in x}`, because if there is a hash collision, we might lose valid data.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [[[1,2],3],[[3,4],5], [[1,2],3]]
z = []
for i in x:
    if i not in z:
    z.append(i)

print z
[[[1, 2], 3], [[3, 4], 5]]
```

Is this what u r looking for??